# Scala: How do I write the type of the function that sortBy takes?

Tags: scala, collections, types, functional-programming

I want to pass the parameter that List.sortBy takes through to another function. My code looks something like this:

```
//Scala
def sortAndMore(list: List[(String, _)], sortFn: Option[???] = None) = {
  val maybeSortedList = sortFn match {
    case None => list
    case Some(fn) => list.sortBy(fn)
  }
  // do some more stuff with this list
}

val myList = ("one", 1)::("three", 3)::("two", 2)::Nil
sortAndMore(myList, Some(_._1 /*???*/))
```

So in the end I want to have the same result as this gives:

```
myList.sortBy(_._1)
```

What is the type of Option in the sortAndMore function?

The [Scala API for scala.collection.immutable.List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) says this:

```
def sortBy [B] (f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): List[A]
```

I tried several things, but I just don't know the correct syntax, and wasn't lucky guessing it. Any hints are very much appreciated, especially with a pointer to why the syntax has to be that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution (compiles on my terminal)

```
def sortAndMore(list: List[(String,_)], sortFn: Option[((String,_))=>String] = None) = {
  val maybeSortedList = sortFn match {
    case Some(fn) => list.sortBy(fn)
    case None => list
  }
}

sortAndMore(myList, Some(_._1))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to have a generic type: `sortAndMore(list: List[(String, _)]`, you hard-coded `Int`.

Comment: Also, I would get rid of the `val maybeSortedList =` so that the list is actually returned (right now the function returns Unit). Otherwise good answer, +1

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I see what you mean, I would thus use this prototype for the function: `def sortAndMore[A](list: List[(String, A)], sortFn: Option[(String, A) => String] = None)`. However if it is still not it, I don't know

Comment: @ChrisJamesC since you're not really using the type information you can also just use _, so the signature becomes `def sortAndMore(list: List[(String, _)], sortFn: Option[((String,_))=>String] = None)`

Comment: Thanks to the three of you, it worked with the generic Type! My error was that I tried to put in the List as well, and didn't know that it simply returned String instead of some Ordering.